axios failed to upload file using base 64 string in React native
I m using following function to call axios
    export const uploadImageBlob1 = (base64Str, mimeType, filename) => {
  // const {uri, type, fileName = "test"} = fileData;
  // console.log({fileName, type})
  if (!isValidBase64(base64Str)) {
    console.error('Invalid base64 string');
    return;
  }

  console.log("its valid base64 string")

  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("image", {
    uri: `data:${mimeType};base64,${base64Str}`,
    type: mimeType,
    name: ` ${filename}`
  });
  // formData.append("test", "hellow wor");
  const headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
  }
  return api(ApiEndpoint.IMAGE, Method.POST, params, Env.BASE_URL, formData, headers)
}

This gives error as network error
if I use
formData.append("test", "hellow worls");
its hitting my back end
some times for some files this works.
Can you help me to resolve this, I want to send files using base 64 strings
